# Spring and JBoss - together forming Rest Web Service

Tags: java, spring, rest, jboss, spring-boot

I am considerably new to Spring. What I know is that Spring boot has an embedded tomcat server which can make my Web Service run on a defined host:port. 
I prefer to use an independent configurable JBoss instead and make a WS. 
I am not sure about the structure of that project, neither do I have a bit of idea what type of context to be declared where!

[image]

This is the project structure that I have created. Not sure if this is correct.
JBoss runs fine but on each request, I am getting 404
Here is the web.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>AdobeSystems</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    </web-app>
```

And here is my controller code:

```
        @RestController
    public class CalculateControllerImpl implements CalculateController{
    private CalculateService calculateService;
    private DataObjectSRO dataObjectSRO;

    public CalculateControllerImpl(){
            calculateService = new CalculateServiceImpl();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody int add(@RequestParam(value="first", defaultValue="10") int first,@RequestParam(value="second", defaultValue="5") int second ) {
            dataObjectSRO.setFirst(first);
            dataObjectSRO.setSecond(second);
            return calculateService.add(dataObjectSRO.getFirst(),dataObjectSRO.getSecond());
    }

    }
```

Comment: Paste your controller code and your jsp/html whatever you have.

Comment: You have to put and configure the `web.xml` to run a WAR package on JBOSS.

Comment: How could we help you with 404 if you only posted your project structure?

Comment: I edited the question with the details needed.

Comment: What is the url you are hitting what is the data you are passing? Just start with a simple helloworld get test before you start param. Jboss or tomcat is later first you need to sort out spring mvc setup. read http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/ and http://www.programming-free.com/2014/01/spring-mvc-40-restful-web-services.html

Comment: The articles are good. Thanks for that. But I have ran the spring hello world programs on Tomcat already. Was trying to go a bit further on JBoss where all these confusions came up!

Comment: instead of <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>, try <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>